# ProgressBar showing after execution

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a problem with a ProgressBar. I have worked with progress bars before and never had this problem.

I have a button that, once clicked, run an asynctask, which can take a lot of time to finish. So, I set up a ProgressBar to show when the button is clicked. The code is this one:

```
Button btnFollowing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFollowing);

    final ProgressBar pbFollowing = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarFollowing);

    btnFollowing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pbFollowing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {                   
                GetFriends gf = new GetFriends(MainActivity.this);
                friends = gf.execute("value").get();        
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("Exception MainActivity gettingfriends", e.toString());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.e("Exception MainActivity gettingfriends", e.toString());
            }
            setStringArrayPref(MainActivity.this, "friends", friends);
            pbFollowing.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the ProgressBar doesn't show up on the screen until the AsyncTask is over, even the setVisible line being before the AsyncTask creation.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Why are you setting it to invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probelm is with this line:

```
friends = gf.execute("value").get();
```

The execute will start the task in the background, but calling get() on it, will wait for the execution to finish and then return the result. Therefore your code will wait in this line until the AsyncTask finishes, and your progress bar will become visible after that because you blocked the main thread with the get call.

You should call the execute method on the AsyncTask and then use the AsyncTask's onPostExecute  to do what you need to do at the end of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask onPre... will run on GUI threead and it will show up
AsyncTask onPost will run on gui thread too and you should dismiss/hide